# How can I use HTTParty with UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: ruby, encoding, httparty

I have a URL like `http://example.com/tag/София/new.json` and I want to make a GET request with HTTParty. When I do:

HTTPArty.get "[http://example.com/tag/София/new.json](http://example.com/tag/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/new.json)

I get:

```
URI::InvalidURIError at /
bad URI(is not URI?): link here
```

Any ideas how to handle this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2718.txt) says "encode the URL as UTF-8, then represent multi-byte sequences as percent-escaped octets." In your case,

```
http://example.com/tag/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/new.json
```

Comment: Could you tell me how you managed to convert "София" to "%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F"?

Comment: @tstyle probably with `URI.escape()`, see http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html